# How can I register a class method with Phalcon's DI?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, anonymous-function, phalcon

In an attempt to loosely couple my Phalcon application with XenForo, I'm trying to register a method from the XenForo_Model_Thread class with Phalcon's DI like this:

```
$di->set('forum', function () {
    \XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader('../forums/library');
    \XenForo_Application::initialize('../forums/library', '../forums', true, array('resetOutputBuffering' => false));
    \XenForo_Session::startPublicSession();

    $model = \XenForo_Model::create('XenForo_Model_Thread');

    $callback = function ($id) use ($model) {
        return $model->getThreadsInForum($id);
    };

    return $callback;
});
```

I'd like to be able to call this method from my controller like this:

```
$forum = $this->forum(2);
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

But this works:

```
$di->set('forum', function () {
    \XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader('../forums/library');
    \XenForo_Application::initialize('../forums/library', '../forums', true, array('resetOutputBuffering' => false));
    \XenForo_Session::startPublicSession();

    $model = \XenForo_Model::create('XenForo_Model_Thread');

    return array($model, 'getThreadsInForum');
});
```

Then I can do this from the controller:

```
$forum = call_user_func($this->forum, 2);
```

I hate to clutter up my code with this weirdness though. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `$di->set('forum', function ($id) {`? I haven't tried it, just a thought.

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos yeah, the error thrown by PHP is "Call to undefined method forum()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a serious PHP deviant, I wouldn't recommend anything like that under a gun point, but this is an interesting question. If you do the same but get the callback first (instead of directly calling it) everything should work as expected.

```
$di->set('forum', function () {
    \XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader('../forums/library');
    \XenForo_Application::initialize('../forums/library', '../forums', true, array('resetOutputBuffering' => false));
    \XenForo_Session::startPublicSession();

    $model = \XenForo_Model::create('XenForo_Model_Thread');

    $callback = function ($id) use ($model) {
        return $model->getThreadsInForum($id);
    };

    return $callback;
});

$callback = $this->forum;
$forum = $callback(2);
```

Why? Because the `__get` magic is implemented in your `Phalcon\DI\Injectable` and `__call` isn't, which is kind of how it should be. You can extend `Injectable` or `Controller` with the following little twist, which would do the trick.

```
function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if (is_callable($callback = $this->$name)){
        return call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);
    }

    // Or throw a bad method call exception…

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It works! But I did end up changing my design. I decided I don't want to call XenForo's methods directly in my code, so instead I register a service that translates XenForo objects into my own.